# Why would a single selector apply to the same element multiple times?

Tags: css, selector, repeat

Not totally sure what is going on here. At first I thought I was loading the same stylesheet multiple times, but that is not the case. Is there a reason why the same selector is being applied to the same element 5 times?

[image]

Comment: Are you using less or sass to compile your CSS files? If you are, extra include statements could cause multiple copies of one style rule to end up in your output.

Comment: It reports the same line number of main.css each time, though.

Comment: Turns out I'm just an idiot. The stylesheet was only being loaded once, but was included several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I was loading the same stylesheet a bunch of times. Oops!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/client/styles/admin/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/client/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/client/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/client/styles/admin/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/client/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/client/styles/admin/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/client/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/client/styles/admin/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/client/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"     />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/client/styles/admin/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/client/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/client/styles/admin/main.css" type="text/css" />
```